# SQL/Doctrine - Filtering results with AND (many to many)

Tags: sql, doctrine, subquery, filtering, where-clause

I have 3 tables (with relation many to many), I would like to select images that only match ALL the selected categories.

(Sample tables below)

**Examples of filtering**:

- (1) Get Images and filter by category: '1' => **Results**: 61, 62
- (2) Get Images and filter by category: '1' AND '2' => **Results**: 61

- (1) Get Images and filter by category: '2' => **Results**: 61, 63, 64
- (2) Get Images and filter by category: '2' AND '3' => **Results**: 61, 64
- (3) Get Images and filter by category: '1' AND '2' AND '3' => **Results**: 61

### CONCLUSION:

I would like to narrow down my search results during adding new categories to filter.
Has anyone encountered such problems?

I was trying to find solutions by WHERE, JOINs clausules, but nothing works properly.
The closest to the solution is to create an additional column with an array containing the categories ID.

```
SELECT
    images.id,
    ARRAY(SELECT images_categories.category_id FROM images_categories where images_categories.image_id = images.id order by images_categories.category_id)
FROM
    images
ORDER BY images.id
```

In WHERE clausule SQL "doesn't see" categories column

```
WHERE
    (1) in categories
```

images

```
+----+------------------------+
| id | Some another fields... |
+----+------------------------+
| 61 | ...                    |
+----+------------------------+
| 62 | ...                    |
+----+------------------------+
| 63 | ...                    |
+----+------------------------+
| 64 | ...                    |
+----+------------------------+
```

categories

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | ...  |
+----+------+
| 2  | ...  |
+----+------+
| 3  | ...  |
+----+------+
```

images_categories (Table with relation)

```
+----------+-------------+
| image_id | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
| 61       | 1           |
+----------+-------------+
| 61       | 2           |
+----------+-------------+
| 61       | 3           |
+----------+-------------+
| 62       | 1           |
+----------+-------------+
| 63       | 2           |
+----------+-------------+
| 64       | 2           |
+----------+-------------+
| 64       | 3           |
+----------+-------------+
```

---

## SOLUTION (SQL + Symfony Doctrine):

After few days of searching solution, my friend send me a fresh perspective on the matter. Below you can find **WORKING** SQL Solution:

```
SELECT images.id
FROM images
LEFT JOIN images_categories
    ON image.id = images_categories.image_id
LEFT JOIN categories
    ON categories.id = images_categories.category_id
WHERE categories.id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY images.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categories.id) = 2;
```

**Explanation:**

```
WHERE categories.id IN (1, 2) // <= Array of categories ids
```

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT categories.id) = 2; // <= Count of categories array
```

---

## Solution in (Symfony) Doctrine:

```
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        $qb
            ->select('image')
            ->from($this->_entityName, 'image')
            ->leftJoin('image.category', 'category');

        // Implemented solution:
        $qb
            ->andWhere('category.id IN (:categoriesIds)')
            ->setParameter('categoriesIds', $categoriesIds)
            ->groupBy('image.id')
            ->having('COUNT(DISTINCT category.id) = :categoriesCount')
            ->setParameter('categoriesCount', count($categoriesIds));

        $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
select I.id
from images as I
where I.id in ( select image_id from images_categories group by image_id having 
COUNT(*) = ( select COUNT(*) as c from
categories ))
```